# Mariadb purge_paths has too many rows (2343154), exiting

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to update mariadb database table using a script and I am getting the following error message.
*"purge_paths has too many rows (2343154), exiting"*

**Already tried the following:**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name MAX_ROWS=5000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=nnn;
mysql> ALTER TABLE purge_paths MAX_ROWS=5000000000 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=999;
Query OK, 2343154 rows affected (25.62 sec)
Records: 2343154  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

Modified myisam_data_pointer_size=7 (Setup in the startup script)

Validated that the dataDir is on Ext4 file system. 
The system has sufficient space on the DataDir and tmpDir.
```

Still getting the same error.

**Mariadb details:** Server version: 5.5.68-MariaDB MariaDB Server

**Providing more details based on the request:**

I have a perl script that will identify the files that are older than 367 days in the source control server and update it to the mysql database on table purge_paths.

While updating the database, I am getting the error message.

Comment: what abour anupgrade? and a change to innodb

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error message? What script are you using? Please [edit] your question to include more information about the script and how you call it.